# Construct Sight Lines 999998 : Unexpected Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, error-999998

My problem occurs when I want to produce Construct Sight Lines. When the process is completed I get an 999998 : Unexpected Error. I see the feature class in my geodatabase. But I can't see the Sight Lines on the Map when I add the Data in the Table Of Contents.

I am using ArcMap 10.5.1

Is there anyone that knows what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the "999998: Unexpected Error" is a complete mystery, as these messages are considered to be the standard operating system errors.

But in this case, the tool does execute and also gave the output feature class, so if the tool is running in the background try running your geoprocessing process in the foreground, kindly follow [Foreground and background processing](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/foreground-and-background-processing.htm) documentation for a better understanding.

Also, try a few more checks given below:-

1. Close ArcMap and navigate to

   `C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Roaming\Esri\Desktop10.5.1\ArcMap\Templates` and rename the Normal.mxt
2. Relaunch ArcMap and Click Customize > ArcMap Options on the main menu and then click the Display Cache tab on the ArcMap Options dialog box. Clear the Cache
3. Once the above checks are made try executing the tool once again